# Get http status code after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im trying to get the http status code of my ajax call using the below code but the xhr.status is always undefined..

```
  function checksession() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST'
                ,url:'CheckSession'
                ,success: validateresult(session_ind)
                ,data: { antiCSRF : '{{acsrf}}',
                       session_id: '{{session_id}}'}
                })
        function validateresult(session_ind,xhr){
                alert(xhr.status)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    //...        
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus , xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }  
});
```

or use :

> **statusCode** : An object of numeric HTTP codes and functions to be
>   called when the response has the corresponding code. For example, the
>   following will alert when the response status is a 404:

```
$.ajax({
   statusCode: {
      404: function() {

      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function checksession() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST'
            ,url:'CheckSession'
            ,success: validateresult(session_ind)
            ,data: { antiCSRF : '{{acsrf}}',
                   session_id: '{{session_id}}'}
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
            },
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus , xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
            } 
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not appear that `xhr` (or, `jqxhr` below) was included as argument to `validateresult` call , only `session_ind`

Try

```
  function checksession() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST'
                ,url:'CheckSession'
                ,success: function (session_ind, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                   validateresult(session_ind, textStatus, jqxhr)
                }
                ,data: { antiCSRF : '{{acsrf}}',
                       session_id: '{{session_id}}'}
                });
        function validateresult(session_ind, textStatus, jqxhr){
                alert(jqxhr.status)
            }
  };
checksession();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/nuukyLn0/